# Unable to save model architecture (bilstm + attention)

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, multilabel-classification, attention-model

I am working on a multi-label text classification problem. I am trying to add attention mechanism with bilstm model. The attention mechanism code is taken from [here](https://www.kaggle.com/hsankesara/news-classification-using-han/notebook). I am not able to save the model architecture and getting an error mentioned below. My tensorflow version -2.2.0

```
from keras import backend as K

def dot_product(x, kernel):
    if K.backend() == 'tensorflow':
        return K.squeeze(K.dot(x, K.expand_dims(kernel)), axis=-1)
    else:
        return K.dot(x, kernel)

class AttentionWithContext(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    """
    # Input shape
        3D tensor with shape: `(samples, steps, features)`.
    # Output shape
        2D tensor with shape: `(samples, features)`.
    """
    def __init__(self,
                 W_regularizer=None, u_regularizer=None, b_regularizer=None,
                 W_constraint=None, u_constraint=None, b_constraint=None,
                 bias=True, **kwargs):

        self.supports_masking = True
        self.init = tf.keras.initializers.get('glorot_uniform')

        self.W_regularizer = tf.keras.regularizers.get(W_regularizer)
        self.u_regularizer = tf.keras.regularizers.get(u_regularizer)
        self.b_regularizer = tf.keras.regularizers.get(b_regularizer)

        self.W_constraint = tf.keras.constraints.get(W_constraint)
        self.u_constraint = tf.keras.constraints.get(u_constraint)
        self.b_constraint = tf.keras.constraints.get(b_constraint)

        self.bias = bias
        super(AttentionWithContext, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        assert len(input_shape) == 3

        self.W = self.add_weight(shape=(input_shape[-1], input_shape[-1],),
                                 initializer=self.init,
                                 name='{}_W'.format(self.name),
                                 regularizer=self.W_regularizer,
                                 constraint=self.W_constraint)
        if self.bias:
            self.b = self.add_weight(shape=(input_shape[-1],),
                                     initializer='zero',
                                     name='{}_b'.format(self.name),
                                     regularizer=self.b_regularizer,
                                     constraint=self.b_constraint)

        self.u = self.add_weight(shape=(input_shape[-1],),
                                 initializer=self.init,
                                 name='{}_u'.format(self.name),
                                 regularizer=self.u_regularizer,
                                 constraint=self.u_constraint)

        super(AttentionWithContext, self).build(input_shape)

    def compute_mask(self, input, input_mask=None):
        # do not pass the mask to the next layers
        return None

    def call(self, x, mask=None):
        uit = dot_product(x, self.W)

        if self.bias:
            uit += self.b

        uit = K.tanh(uit)
        ait = dot_product(uit, self.u)

        a = K.exp(ait)

        # apply mask after the exp. will be re-normalized next
        if mask is not None:
            # Cast the mask to floatX to avoid float64 upcasting in theano
            a *= K.cast(mask, K.floatx())

        # in some cases especially in the early stages of training the sum may be almost zero
        # and this results in NaN's. A workaround is to add a very small positive number ε to the sum.
        # a /= K.cast(K.sum(a, axis=1, keepdims=True), K.floatx())
        a /= K.cast(K.sum(a, axis=1, keepdims=True) + K.epsilon(), K.floatx())

        a = K.expand_dims(a)
        weighted_input = x * a
        return K.sum(weighted_input, axis=1)

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape[0], input_shape[-1]


def lstm_with_attention(embedding_matrix,
                        **kwargs):
  STAMP = kwargs['STAMP']
  max_seq_length = kwargs['max_seq_length']
  EMBEDDING_DIM = kwargs['EMBEDDING_DIM']
  nb_words = kwargs['nb_words']

  inp = tf.keras.Input(shape=(max_seq_length,))
  embedded_seq = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(nb_words,
                EMBEDDING_DIM,
                weights=[embedding_matrix],
                trainable=False)(inp)
  x_1_bilstm = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.compat.v1.keras.layers.CuDNNLSTM(128, return_sequences=True))(embedded_seq)
  x_1_bn = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(x_1_bilstm)
  x_2_bilstm = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.compat.v1.keras.layers.CuDNNLSTM(64, return_sequences=True))(x_1_bn)
  attention = AttentionWithContext()(x_2_bilstm)
  x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation="relu")(attention)
  x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(x)
  model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inp, outputs=x)
  optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
  model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
  model.summary()

  with open(STAMP + ".json", "w") as json_file: json_file.write(model.to_json())
  return model, attention
```

Building lstm with attention

```
embedding_matrix, nb_words = get_embedding('glove',word_index)
model, attention_layer = lstm_with_attention(embedding_matrix,STAMP=STAMP,max_seq_length=max_seq_length,nb_words=nb_words,EMBEDDING_DIM=EMBEDDING_DIM)
```

Error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-4be6d63890f7> in <module>()
     20 # # BiGRU CuDNN
     21 embedding_matrix, nb_words = get_embedding('glove',word_index)
---> 22 model, attention_layer = lstm_with_attention(embedding_matrix,STAMP=STAMP,max_seq_length=max_seq_length,nb_words=nb_words,EMBEDDING_DIM=EMBEDDING_DIM)
     23 # gru_model = make_cudnn_gru_f(max_seq_length,embedding_matrix,loss_func=macro_soft_f1,eval_metric=macro_f1)
     24 # model = gru_model()

7 frames
<ipython-input-51-1ae8a90521d0> in lstm_with_attention(embedding_matrix, **kwargs)
    115   model.summary()
    116 
--> 117   with open(STAMP + ".json", "w") as json_file: json_file.write(model.to_json())
    118   return model, attention
    119 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py in to_json(self, **kwargs)
   1296         A JSON string.
   1297     """
-> 1298     model_config = self._updated_config()
   1299     return json.dumps(
   1300         model_config, default=serialization.get_json_type, **kwargs)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py in _updated_config(self)
   1274     from tensorflow.python.keras import __version__ as keras_version  # pylint: disable=g-import-not-at-top
   1275 
-> 1276     config = self.get_config()
   1277     model_config = {
   1278         'class_name': self.__class__.__name__,

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py in get_config(self)
    966     if not self._is_graph_network:
    967       raise NotImplementedError
--> 968     return copy.deepcopy(get_network_config(self))
    969 
    970   @classmethod

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py in get_network_config(network, serialize_layer_fn)
   2117           filtered_inbound_nodes.append(node_data)
   2118 
-> 2119     layer_config = serialize_layer_fn(layer)
   2120     layer_config['name'] = layer.name
   2121     layer_config['inbound_nodes'] = filtered_inbound_nodes

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py in serialize_keras_object(instance)
    273         return serialize_keras_class_and_config(
    274             name, {_LAYER_UNDEFINED_CONFIG_KEY: True})
--> 275       raise e
    276     serialization_config = {}
    277     for key, item in config.items():

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py in serialize_keras_object(instance)
    268     name = get_registered_name(instance.__class__)
    269     try:
--> 270       config = instance.get_config()
    271     except NotImplementedError as e:
    272       if _SKIP_FAILED_SERIALIZATION:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in get_config(self)
    634       raise NotImplementedError('Layer %s has arguments in `__init__` and '
    635                                 'therefore must override `get_config`.' %
--> 636                                 self.__class__.__name__)
    637     return config
    638 

NotImplementedError: Layer AttentionWithContext has arguments in `__init__` and therefore must override `get_config`.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a TensorFlow feature to notify you that it does not know how to reconstruct your layers since it does not know how to process your configs. Here is a quote from tensorflow's document:

> get_config()

> Returns the config of the layer.

> A layer config is a Python dictionary (serializable) containing the configuration of a layer. The same layer can be reinstantiated later (without its trained weights) from this configuration.

> The config of a layer does not include connectivity information, nor the layer class name. These are handled by Network (one layer of abstraction above).

To solve the problem, all you need is to create a `get_config` method corresponding to `__init__` in your class to instruct TensorFlow how to reinstantiate your layer.

```
def get_config(self):
    config = super().get_config().copy()
    config.update({
            'W_regularizer': self.W_regularizer,
            'u_regularizer': self.u_regularizer,
            'b_regularizer': self.b_regularizer,
            'W_constraint': self.W_constraint,
            'u_constraint': self.u_constraint,
            'b_constraint': self.b_constraint,
            'bias': self.bias,
    })
    return config
```

Then you should be able to save and load it.

Comment: LIFE SAVER! Thank you so much. Works like a charm.